# Flex: Setting "Server Type" ...why?

Tags: apache-flex

Whenever I make a new Flex project it always asks me "Server Type". So far I have always checked "none", Although my server type is PHP and I usually access .php scripts to get information from data-bases just fine with server type not set. So what is server-type for? what does it do for me? if I can get some extra benefits from it I want to do that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a Flex application, you are asked the server type so that Flex can properly configure itself for your Application server, not web server. This is only if you're Flex application is going to be backed by an application server. In your case, you're just calling some PHP scripts and don't require full blown application server support.